# Why Chrome don't print Element.classList property with a console.log()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom, element

According to this document https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList , the classList property is a DOMTokenList Object in the Element class.

With Chrome, when I print `console.log(document.Element.prototype);` I can't find any classList property, but when I do that

```
if (("classList" in document.createElement("_"))) {...}
```

The condition is true. In an other hand, when I do that

```
if (!('classList' in window.Element)) {...}
```

The condition is also TRUE ! There should be something I'm missing but what ?

Comment: `window.Element.classList` is `undefined` in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It should probably be `Element` constrictor.

Comment: Have you tried `HTMLElement.prototype`?

Comment: @Bergi that seems to be a Firefox thing; Chrome says it's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a property of the Element *prototype*, it's a property of each DOM node (well, each element node).

Understand that the DOM API is specified in a way that describes what code can expect of DOM objects, but it doesn't say *how* that functionality works in any particular implementation (which is kind-of silly but there you go).

Comment: Thanks you a lot ! I was expecting Element to be part of the DOM (and so to be DOM node). My final goal was to check if classList was available in SVGElement. So I did it this way : `if (!('classList' in document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","a"))) {...}` . I find it a bit silly but I have no idea how to do it better.